# The Weights of Edges that aren't in a Minimum Spanning Tree.

Tags: graph-theory

> 1. Let $G$ be a graph with edge weight $w$. Let $T^\ast$ be a minimum spanning tree, and let $e$ be an edge in $G$ but not in $T^\ast$. We know that $T^\ast + e$ contains exactly $1$ cycle $C$. Prove that for all $e' \in E(C)$, we have $w(e') \leq w(e)$.
> 2. Suppose that no two edges in $G$ have the same weight. Prove that $G$ has a unique minimum spanning tree.

Comment: What have you tried? The first part follows a pretty direct path: show that if there was an edge of higher weight, your tree couldn't have been minimal after all.  

For the second: do you mean that "no 2 edges in $G$ have the same weight"?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** if $e' \in E(T)$ then show that $T^\ast + e-e'$ is also a spanning tree of $G$, thus, as $T^*$ is minimal you have

$$\sum_{e'' \in T^*}w(e'') \leq \sum_{e'' \in T^\ast + e-e'}w(e'') \,.$$

What is

$$\sum_{e'' \in T^\ast + e-e'}w(e'') - \sum_{e'' \in T^*}w(e'')  \,?$$

As for the second question I assume the problem sais **NO two edges** have the same weight, otherwise $C_n$ with all weights equal is a counterexample.

If that is the case, assume by contradiction that $T_1,T_2$ are two minimal spanning trees. Look at $E(T_1) \Delta E(T_2)$, one of those edges must have maximal weight.  What happens if you erase this one and add one from the other tree? You just have to add it carefully so it creates a tree....

Comment: Hah sorry yea, it is supposed to be no 2 edges have the same weight. Thanks for this, I'll work on it and report back!

Comment: Sorry, can you tell me why you can assume that w(e - e') is >= 0? Since we just know that e ∈ G, and e' ∈ E(C).

Comment: @user81008 What is $$\sum_{e'' \in T^\ast + e-e'}w(e'') - \sum_{e'' \in T^*}w(e'')  \,?$$ You know it is positive ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint 1:** As there is only one cycle in $T^*+e$, you will break it, if you remove $e'$. Also, removeing $e'$ will not disconnect the graph, hence $T^*+e-e'$ is again a spanning tree. Now, compare the weights of both trees.

In the second part, there is a typo, you certainly want to assume that *no* two edges share the same weight. Then:

**Hint 2:** Let $T_1,T_2$ be two non-equal spanning trees. Then there is an edge $e$ in $T_1$ which is not in $T_2$. Use part 1 on this $e$.

Comment: For the second hint, there might be multiple edges not in $T_1$ and not in $T_2$, and you can only use part 1 once. Once you used part 1, the new tree is not minimal, so repeating might decrease the total weight.